# MVC3 DropDownList not validating with [Required] class field as type int?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Any idea why the following dropdownlist won't validate with required field as type int (the "Title" field below)?

```
    [Required]             // This works!
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]             // This doesn't work 
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public int TitleId { get; set; }



     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "This can't be blank!")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TitleId, "Title")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TitleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.TitleId, String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TitleId)
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: When you post your data, does TitleId have a value assigned?

Comment: If int? still not working, maybe you set a default value for your dropdown? ie: (0, "all records") instead of a null value?

Comment: No go...I set it to "-Select Me-" and unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this work item](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7629), client-side validation breaks when the SelectList in the ViewBag uses the same name as the field in question. (i.e. both are `TitleId` in your case.)

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
    model.TitleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.TitleIdList, String.Empty)
```

with your SelectList renamed to `TitleIdList` accordingly.

Comment: $$$$$ Thanks for the post!  That was it!

Answer (score 3):

`[Required]` only works for nullable objects and int cannot be nullable.
Try using `int?` instead of `int`

Comment: No go!  This is bizarre.  What baffles me is I have another dropdownlist that is nullable of type int: 

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Order ID")]
        public Nullable<int> OrderId { get; set; }

And validation catches it if it's blank (the "OrderId").  But that value ("OrderId") is nullable in my object binding model (the database) whereas the "Title" is not nullable in the database.  That is the only difference, unless I need to generate a new view since I changed that type to int?.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Min Attribute from the Data Annotations extension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Min/Create) ?

Answer (score 1):

Or else try with this. Add the below code in your site.css file

```
select.input-validation-error {
    /*border: 1px solid #e80c4d;*/
    /*Other styles*/
}
```

This will show the drop down border color as red, when it is empty.

And in View page:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TitleID, Model.TitleIDList, "-- Select --", new { @class = "dropdownlist" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TitleID, "This can't be blank")
```